# Faster way to apply string point mutations?

Tags: python, string, tuples, bioinformatics

I have a csv file whose lines are a bunch of mutations at various positions. I have a tuple with 24 strings corresponding to chromosomes to which I apply these mutations sequentially. The program speed is not as fast as I am expecting and I am not sure if it is the string concatenation that is slowing this code down or the tuple rejoining. Is there an easier way to apply these point mutations (or aggregated group of point mutations). Here is the current code:

```
def applySimpleMutation(chromosome, st_idx, ed_idx, mutation_from_string, mutation_to_string, chromosome_tuple): 
    actual_st_idx = st_idx-1 #it is one indexed
    actual_ed_idx = ed_idx #This is because python string indexing doesnt include the last one 
    if(chromosome == 'X'): 
        tup_idx = 22
    elif(chromosome == 'Y'): 
        tup_idx = 23
    else: 
        tup_idx = int(chromosome)-1
    chrom_string = chromosome_tuple[tup_idx]
    start_string = chrom_string[:actual_st_idx]
    continue_string = chrom_string[actual_ed_idx:]
    if(mutation_to_string == '-'): 
        final_string = start_string + continue_string
    else:
        final_string = start_string + mutation_to_string+ continue_string
    final_tuple = chromosome_tuple[:tup_idx] + (final_string,) + chromosome_tuple[tup_idx+1:]
    return final_tuple
```

Code looping over dataframe:

```
def mutateWithDataframe(df, r): 
    for index, row in tqdm(df.iterrows(), total = df.shape[0]):
        chromosome = str(row['chromosome'])
        st_idx = int(row['chromosome_start'])
        ed_idx = int(row['chromosome_end'])
        mutation_from_string = str(row['mutated_from_allele'])
        mutation_to_string = str(row['mutated_to_allele'])
        r = applySimpleMutation(chromosome, st_idx, ed_idx, mutation_from_string, mutation_to_string, r)
    return r
```

Comment: For every mutation, you completely re-write the 24 chromosomes within the tuple. Wouldn't it make more sense to only save the chromosome being changed? Use a mutable list instead of an immutable tuple.

Comment: Last time I did that, the mutations were not persistent or didn't behave in the way I expected, I guess due to mutability of the list. Maybe in this case it probably doesnt matter because its just a single position variant, let me retry the speed for that.

Answer (score 0):

For every mutation, you completely re-write the 24 chromosomes within the tuple. Wouldn't it make more sense to only save the chromosome being changed? Use a mutable list instead of an immutable tuple. You can simply write to the indexed values of the original list. Demo below.

```
def applySimpleMutation(chromosome, st_idx, ed_idx, mutation_from_string, mutation_to_string, chromosome_li): 
    actual_st_idx = st_idx-1 #it is one indexed
    actual_ed_idx = ed_idx #This is because python string indexing doesnt include the last one 
    if(chromosome == 'X'): 
        _idx = 22
    elif(chromosome == 'Y'): 
        _idx = 23
    else: 
        _idx = int(chromosome)-1
    chrom_string = chromosome_li[_idx]
    start_string = chrom_string[:actual_st_idx]
    continue_string = chrom_string[actual_ed_idx:]
    if(mutation_to_string == '-'): 
        chromosome_li[_idx] = start_string + continue_string
    else:
        chromosome_li[_idx] = start_string + mutation_to_string+ continue_string
```

`df` is a dataframe containing mutation information

`r` is a lit containing chromosomes

```
def mutateWithDataframe(df, r):
    for index, row in tqdm(df.iterrows(), total = df.shape[0]):
        chromosome = str(row['chromosome'])
        st_idx = int(row['chromosome_start'])
        ed_idx = int(row['chromosome_end'])
        mutation_from_string = str(row['mutated_from_allele'])
        mutation_to_string = str(row['mutated_to_allele'])
        applySimpleMutation(chromosome, st_idx, ed_idx, mutation_from_string, mutation_to_string, r)
    return r
```

This should provide the same output but have noticeably better performance.

Comment: Update: this actually isnt that much faster than the original implementation for me.